# Will IoT Edge buffering retry messages not delivered due to IoT Hub Throttling?

Tags: azure-iot-edge

Do we get the same behaviour of IoT Edge displayed when IoT Hub is throttling the messages that we do when there is no connectivity, i.e. will those messages be buffered and retried?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you do. However, messages can be dropped by edgeHub if it can’t deliver the message before message TTL expires.